# CMAKE Error: Could not create named generator CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24278599/14309129) did not solve my problem, I haven't made any misspelling.

How do I fix **CMAKE ERROR: Could not create named generator CMakeLists.txt**?

The reason why I run `cMake -G` is to get rid of [this error, and this answer said I should so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935066/14309129).

Side-question: Do I have to have VScode installed in order to use cMake, because currently I don't. Perhaps that is the root of the problem? Just seems overkill to install VScode just to use cMake.

The project I am trying to use cMake on: https://github.com/kosua20/MIDIVisualizer

```
C:\Users\sebas\Downloads\MIDIVisualizer-master\MIDIVisualizer-master>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 44F3-0CFE

 Directory of C:\Users\sebas\Downloads\MIDIVisualizer-master\MIDIVisualizer-master

20-09-2020  11:56    <DIR>          .
20-09-2020  11:56    <DIR>          ..
22-08-2020  22:23    <DIR>          .github
22-08-2020  22:23               117 .gitignore
22-08-2020  22:23             4.643 CMakeLists.txt
22-08-2020  22:23             9.022 help.png
22-08-2020  22:23    <DIR>          libs
22-08-2020  22:23             1.072 LICENSE
22-08-2020  22:23             5.755 README.md
22-08-2020  22:23    <DIR>          resources
22-08-2020  22:23           280.222 result1.png
22-08-2020  22:23           896.710 result2.png
22-08-2020  22:23           547.183 result3.png
22-08-2020  22:23    <DIR>          src
               8 File(s)      1.744.724 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  273.283.190.784 bytes free

C:\Users\sebas\Downloads\MIDIVisualizer-master\MIDIVisualizer-master>cMake -G CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: Could not create named generator CMakeLists.txt

Generators
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
* NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.


C:\Users\sebas\Downloads\MIDIVisualizer-master\MIDIVisualizer-master>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbG9t.png)

Comment: "How do I fix CMAKE ERROR: Could not create named generator CMakeLists.txt?" - The error message clearly states that your generator - `CMakeLists.txt` - doesn't match any known for CMake. The proper choice of a generator depends on what do you want (and what do you have). If you have installed Visual Studio, and want to use it, then use corresponded Visual Studio generator from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

- I installed VS Code Studio
- Important: remember to check off C++
- go into "developer command prompt for VS 2019"
- `cd` into project folder
- Run "CMake CMakeLists.txt"

Comment: There is no such thing like "VS Code Studio". There are "Visual Studio" and "Visual Studio Code" (or, in short, "VS Code").